# Integration of first kind zero order bessel function J(x)

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, laplace-transform

What is the integration of first kind zero order Bessel function  $J(kx)$, where 
$k$ is constant and the 
limits of $x$ are from $0$ to $a$.

i.e., $$\int_0^{a} J_0(kx) dx = ?$$

Answer (score 4):

If you look [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/01/01/), you wil find that

$$\int J_0(t)\,dt =\frac{\pi  t}{2}  \pmb{H}_0(t) J_1(t)+\frac{t}{2} (2 -\pi  \pmb{H}_1(t)) J_0(t)$$ where appears the Struve function.

This makes 
$$\int_0^a J_0(kx)\,dx =\frac{a}{2}  (\pi  \pmb{H}_0(a k) J_1(a k)+(2-\pi  \pmb{H}_1(a k)) J_0(a k))$$

Comment: Do you know how to obtain this relation?

Comment: I wish there was a derivation for this formula lol

Answer (score 1):

Honestly speaking, for the limit $0$ to $a$, I have no idea how to solve, but if it is $0 $ to $\infty$, then you can follow this way $:$

We have $$L\{J_0(x):p\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad L\{J_0(kx)\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+p^2}}. . . . . (1)$$ ( from Laplace transformation and using the scaling property )

By the definition of Laplace transformation, $$L\{J_0(x):p\}=\int_0^{\infty} J_0(x) e^{-px} dx$$

So from $(1)$, $$\int_0^{\infty} J_0(kx) e^{-px} dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+p^2}}$$

Putting $p=0$ we have, $$\int_0^{\infty} J_0(kx)  dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+0}}=\frac{1}{k}$$